# Data inside the webview fit to screen height and width

Tags: android, html, webview

I have html text shown in below link
http://pastebin.com/KVTUnhXL
My issue is when I try to load it in webview it looks very small. My requirement is by default it should occupy device height and width so that it looks proper 
below is my code

```
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Please help.

Below is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_general">


    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add your xml file where you have defined mWebView

Comment: String content = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"+
           "<html><head>"+
           "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />"+
           "<head><body>";
   content += result + "</body></html>";

Comment: The Link is not a responsive which means compatible with device height and width. Check with other link whether it shows entire screen or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple one:

**To set the HTML to use the full Viewport**:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

in the HTML body tag.

**To remove margin and padding from HTML Page:**

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**If you load content from a remote webserver use a HTML Processing Library such as [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)**

Comment: thanks it works I have invested a lots of effort in this going through webview documentation and set zoom levels